# Why do we pull from remote master branch into local master branch and our working branch?

Tags: git

Everytime we make a pull in our repository in our organization, we pull from the remote master branch into our local master branch and our current working branch(which is usually named as the ticket we're working on). Why do we need to update our local master branch too?

So, we do -

```
git checkout master
git stash
git pull origin master
git stash apply
##And then resolve conflicts
```

And then -

```
git checkout ticketNumber
git stash
git pull origin master
git stash apply
##And then resolve conflicts
```

Is this inefficient? We're running the same commands on two branches, everyday.

Comment: "We" don't do that. In particular, *I* don't do that. You don't even need a `master` branch in your own repository (though I rarely bother deleting mine). Overall though, you're quite right: it's wasted effort.

Comment: Okay, but is it a good practice to keep a local master branch? We could pull from our local master like- git checkout ticketNumber; git stash; git pull master; git stash apply? Would these sequence of commands work too?

Comment: Whether to keep a local master/main depends on whether you want to do anything with it. What I do is (a) never (or hardly ever) use `git pull` at all; (b) use `git fetch`; (c) use `git merge` and/or `git rebase` as needed. I also generally avoid `git stash` in favor of just making commits. For the cases where `git stash` might sometimes be useful, I have instead used `git worktree`.

Comment: Why is there a stash on master? You're working on master directly??

Comment: I first always checkout the local master and by default do a git stash, the changes I make in my local ticketNumber branch are also there in my local master branch. Is this wrong? @matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

- Stash at the right time.

There is no point in saying `checkout` and *then* `stash`. The time to stash is before the checkout. That way, we are checking out a clean branch and there can be no extra stuff in it. The pull will then be a fast forward and no "conflict" can arise.

So you would be on your feature branch: `git stash`, then `git checkout master`, then `git pull`. This should give a clean fast-forward.

Then you can return to your feature branch and apply the stash as desired.

Okay, but read on...

- Don't switch branches if you don't have to.

You do not have to switch to `master` at all if your only goal is to pull it. Assuming that this would be a fast forward, which it ought to be, you can just stay on your feature branch.

To pull to master while on your feature branch, say:

```
git fetch origin master:master
```

That will update local master from remote master, without your ever having to check out master.

But now read on again...

- Don't even *have* a local master.

What is the local master even for? If you are not going to work on it directly, and if your merges to master are done with pull requests, your local master serves no purpose. It's not inefficient to have it, but it's pointless. You already have all the master commits in your remote tracking branch origin/master; the local master is nonfunctional.

Just stay on your feature branch. `git fetch` to update your remote-tracking `origin/master`, and then stash and then `git merge origin/master` (or even better, if you have not pushed your feature branch yet, `git rebase origin/master`) to get your feature branch up to date with what has happened on master. Now apply the stash.

But read on again...

- Don't stash.

If the goal is to avoid issues when merging origin/master into the feature, don't stash; add and commit. Now merge. You now resolve conflicts in an orderly milieu.